# recoding many variables in a same way, using mutate_at and list with dplyr

Tags: r, list, dplyr

I've got 20 variables (V1, V2, ...) coded "Y" or "N". I want to recode them "1" or "2" with variable names like this "R_V1", "R_V2".

Thanks for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mutate_all` and `recode` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_all(list(R = ~recode(., Y = 1, N = 2)))
```

Or in base R we can use `lapply` :

```
df[paste0('R_', names(df))] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x == 'Y', 1, 2))
```